# Many Vagrant(Virtualbox) machines on one host station and dynamic allocation of resources

Tags: memory-management, vagrant, virtualbox

I have one host machine and want to run many(10) virtual machines(Virtualbox + Vagrant).

And I want to dynamically allocate resources like CPU and RAM.

If I'll give each VM 2 GB of RAM my host machine must have at least 20 GB od RAM memory. But maybe better is to dynamically give each VM from 512MB to 4GB of RAM - depends on current needs.

If I know probably it isn't vagrant thing, VirtualBox rather.

I was reading about `memory ballooning` in VB, but I'm not sure I understand how it works and what actually is this balloon. How to configure it and how many MB set to maximum etc.

The same thing about CPU - I'm not sure how to configure it and how it should works.

My question is
If I have host machine with 12 CPUs and 24GB od RAM and want to run 10 vagrant machines - how can I configure it to dynamically allocate this resources?

Answer (score 1):

here is a script (I am not sure where I have taken, its in my notes) that can be used to configure based on the current spec machine - you can adjust based on your needs, how many VMs you will start an so on

I understand it does not fully answer the question of a dynamic VM allocation once it is up.

```
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
      host = RbConfig::CONFIG['host_os']
      # Give VM 1/4 system memory & access to all cpu cores on the host
      if host =~ /darwin/
        cpus = `sysctl -n hw.ncpu`.to_i
        # sysctl returns Bytes and we need to convert to MB
        mem = `sysctl -n hw.memsize`.to_i / 1024 / 1024 / 4
      elsif host =~ /linux/
        cpus = `nproc`.to_i
        # meminfo shows KB and we need to convert to MB
        mem = `grep 'MemTotal' /proc/meminfo | sed -e 's/MemTotal://' -e 's/ kB//'`.to_i / 1024 / 4
      else
        cpus = `wmic cpu get NumberOfCores`.split("\n")[2].to_i
        mem = `wmic OS get TotalVisibleMemorySize`.split("\n")[2].to_i / 1024 /4
      end

      v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", mem]
      v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", cpus]
  end
```